# Error validating transaction: Transaction orphaned, missing reference (TESTNET)

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, p2sh, non-standard-transaction, p2sh-p2wpkh

**RAWTRANSACTION HEX**

> 02000000000101ccfa268b70e83439c7d7e0cedf5c17b0446ec514e4e890af468cbf0179b278b200000000220020df63ee1a6210873eeb7d10e286a0fad13a7982fe685d35fa0c2d5a915f4a52f9ffffffff01606d0000000000001976a9146a231411dfa9f88dd3f0e3e2ee3d68ef90c3930a88ac011b0a28c30fb9118ed1da72e70ac4f89c0164756e8a021d517577768800000000

**DECODE.**

```
Decoded Transaction
{
    "addresses": [
        "2NFS3VQLTMALkZzDh1zP7X4XF1K5mfjMJ6F",
        "mqC9wgGY254enSQKhDbtdtuGWLXKfHWBQQ"
    ],
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": -1,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "double_spend": false,
    "fees": 1000,
    "hash": "b8a8af826dd000035ab4387b4e9f8351a3e2f2b2115a048ac86866a1302a6530",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                "2NFS3VQLTMALkZzDh1zP7X4XF1K5mfjMJ6F"
            ],
            "age": 2582025,
            "output_index": 0,
            "output_value": 29000,
            "prev_hash": "b278b27901bf8c46af90e8e414c56e44b0175cdfcee0d7c73934e8708b26facc",
            "script": "0020df63ee1a6210873eeb7d10e286a0fad13a7982fe685d35fa0c2d5a915f4a52f9",
            "script_type": "pay-to-script-hash",
            "sequence": 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                "mqC9wgGY254enSQKhDbtdtuGWLXKfHWBQQ"
            ],
            "script": "76a9146a231411dfa9f88dd3f0e3e2ee3d68ef90c3930a88ac",
            "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
            "value": 28000
        }
    ],
    "preference": "low",
    "received": "2024-03-15T05:08:37.0168363Z",
    "relayed_by": "3.238.117.234",
    "size": 150,
    "total": 28000,
    "ver": 2,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 1,
    "vsize": 127
}
```

unlocking script is 0a28c30fb9118ed1da72e70ac4f89c0164756e8a021d5175777688

witness
0020df63ee1a6210873eeb7d10e286a0fad13a7982fe685d35fa0c2d5a915f4a52f9

can someone please help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

> **Transaction orphaned, missing reference**

I suspect your `prev_hash` is wrong, maybe you used the wrong endianness?

Related: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/issues/1332

---

<sup>Update after further information:</sup>

> **i build the transaction on [...] bc-2.jp/tools/txeditor2.html**

I suggest checking the items I have marked with arrows

[image: web page with input fields for building a Bitcoin tx]

Comment: i build the transaction on this site. @redgrittybrick

bc-2.jp/tools/txeditor2.html

the txid is 078ad0a16bc2eaf304ce27655a5d6a013b5243327fcb2b4791395b8b79076d8c

Comment: @Tepan: see updated answer.

Comment: i make by hands using new unlocking script

Base58 address 2N7g6hoqwLo7KRgUNJTJFMXsx6jsJZk5D8C
Redeem Script Hex 51040928a14851
Redeem Script Asm OP_1 0928a148 OP_1
Redeem Script Hash Hex 9e4614600a7607b3f1de255dec5fd98bf62b822b
ScriptPubKey Hex a9149e4614600a7607b3f1de255dec5fd98bf62b822b87
ScriptPubKey Asm OP_HASH160 <9e4614600a7607b3f1de255dec5fd98bf62b822b> OP_EQUAL

Comment: 010000000158c8ec75419da95ffb2b72ebb57c814b3ab2575d95db3541c9a7fcf8207b86b6000000000751040928a14851ffffffff01d0010100000000001976a9146a231411dfa9f88dd3f0e3e2ee3d68ef90c3930a88ac00000000

still same..

Error validating transaction: Transaction 87a9646b64b384d7fb2ec7ea842796f2ddb59ccc064b8946f273639f5f890287 orphaned, missing reference b6867b20f8fca7c94135db955d57b23a4b817cb5eb722bfb5fa99d4175ecc858.

can you help me to spend that fund (tesnet TBTC) ?